# Xcode - IF statement fails in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, if-statement, cell

This is what I currently have:

In cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if ([userSelection  isEqualToString:comparison]){

    changeHeight = NO;

} else if(![userSelection isEqualToString:comparison]) {
    [cell setHidden:YES];
    changeHeight = YES;
}
return cell;
```

Here is the heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(changeHeight == YES) {
    return 0;
} else return 44;

changeHeight = NO;
}
```

The if statement is the cellForRowAtIndexPath works perfectly, but the one in the heightForRowAtIndexPath doesn't evaluate and always returns 44 - no matter is the equality in cellForRowAtIndexPath is true or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not holding state correctly and are making the assumption that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` will be called immediately after `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called.  That *might* be true, but I would expect the order of calling to be undefined and it might not even be calling with respect to the same cell.

So you need to keep state on a per-cell basis, rather than a single "changeHeight" flag.

Now I cannot design all that for you, but you simply need to extend your model data to hold what you want the height of each cell to be.

Also think about what this statement does (it's not related to your question, but you still need to sort it out):

```
if ([userSelection  isEqualToString:comparison]){

} else if(![userSelection isEqualToString:comparison]) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I understand. Can't figure out what is wrong with the statement though. Its probably really obvious, but I can't see it

Comment: @user3580512 Hehe, OK if `x == 'y'` then there is no need for `else if x != 'y'`.  You can replace that `else if (...)` with just `else`.

Comment: Oh damn, how did I not see that. I think I need a break! Thanks

Comment: Actually you might not need to extend your model data if you can test the same condition in each delegate/datasource method. @Tapas Pal's answer might be all you need.

Comment: Trojan, seriously, a huge thanks. All I had to do was extend the model out and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is get called just before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It's better to do like below.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([userSelection  isEqualToString:comparison])?44.0f:0.0f;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setHidden:![userSelection  isEqualToString:comparison]];
    /* Your stuff */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a whirl sometime soon

Answer (score 0):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Hence `changeHeight` does not have correct state. And think about `trojanfoe's` question with your `if...else`.